# Removing Raster from Map View using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, georeferencing, basemap

I am converting from ArcMap to ArcGIS Pro 3.x.  I have a number of rasters that were georeferenced in ArcMap that I have brought over to Pro.  I have - I think - worked out a way to place these rasters on the base map and then import their ArcMap control point tables; each map must added and its control point table imported one at a time.

Unfortunately a few days ago I bulk-added almost all of these rasters to the base map. [If I had caught this then I could have executed undo.]  Because they had not yet been georeferenced, as they were added, they all piled one on the other at some random place on the base map, discoverable by Zoom to Layer .  As a result, the ability to georeference them or import their control tables is disabled.  I need to remove all of these rasters from the base map and then will add and georeference them one at a time.

I've searched ESRI help and cannot find an explanation of how to remove these rasters.

How do I do this?

To be clear I do not want to delete these from the project, only remove them from the map view.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking, but have you selected the raster layer in the Contents panel, right click > remove? You can Use Shift key to select multiple layers in the contents panel.

Comment: Thanks very much for the edits and advice.  ESRI vocabulary sometimes eludes me and so I get cautious.  In this case I was thinking that remove might have meant delete.  However, your advice was well taken and indeed, remove did just what was needed.  Thank you very much.  Now to work on getting import control points to work for all of the 30 some historic maps that I have imported from ArcMap.  Many thanks.